# Change column size/length in Kibana4 search

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Searching through data in Kibana4, if you try to add a field to the table as a column, you can't adjust its column length or size. This normally would be fine, like it is in Kibana3's Panels where the column sizes are all the same percentage from eachother, but it seems you can't replicate the same thing in Kibana4 with "Discover" searches.

I have a search I added to a dashboard. The `message` column is extremely long, unnecessarily so. The `email` field is just as important as `message` and occasionally goes off-screen if a `message` is too long, requiring a user to scroll to the right. Simply moving `email` before `message` doesn't solve this, as `message` would then also go off screen. I need to re-size `message`.

[image]

Is this possible? I tried looking in Settings, didn't see any column-size setting or value, couldn't find anything in documentation about it.

This is what kibana3 looks like and is preferred

[image]

No matter how long any column's contents gets, no column goes off screen.

Comment: Seems like a good use of formatters, but they don't offer max() for strings.

Comment: It's an open issue with kibana; see https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/737